# Samba sync password with Unix

Tags: linux, passwords, samba, pam

I'm trying to set up Samba to sync passwords with Unix (i.e. when someone changes their password via passwd their Samba password is also changed). I've tried following the "Password Synchronization Configuration" section of the [Samba docs](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/pam.html):

```
#%PAM-1.0
# password-sync
#
auth       requisite    pam_nologin.so
auth       required     pam_unix.so
account    required     pam_unix.so
password   requisite    pam_cracklib.so retry=3
password   requisite    pam_unix.so shadow md5 use_authtok try_first_pass
password   required     pam_smbpass.so nullok use_authtok try_first_pass
session    required     pam_unix.so
```

But after following those directions (adding the above to a file in /etc/pam.d) and changing a user's password with passwd, the Samba password remains the same. I've looked around superuser already, and I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/478521/samba-sync-password-with-unix-password-on-debian-wheezy) but the link that contains all the info is broken. I have pam_smbpass.so installed on my computer, so that isn't the issue here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [samba sync password with unix password on debian wheezy](http://superuser.com/questions/478521/samba-sync-password-with-unix-password-on-debian-wheezy)